# Polymer: how to dynamically import an element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Can anyone tell me how I could import an element depending on the value of a Polymer attribute?
I thought I could use data binding but... It's not working. Is it possible to import an element dynamically?

code exemple here:

```
<link rel="import" href="app-window/{{name}}-app.html"> 
//This was my first idea (obviously doesn't work)


<polymer-element name="window-base" attributes="name" >
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="window-base.css">
        <section id="app">
            <!--here will go the instance-->
        </section>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('window-base', {
            name: "Finder",
            ready: function () {
                this.instanceApp();
            },
            instanceApp: function () {
            //this depends on the import made
                var app=document.createElement(this.name + "-app");
                this.$.app.appendChild(app);    
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to build an element that could get an attribute as another element thanks to these answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

according to the Polymer 1.0 migration guide:

> The global Polymer.import function is replaced by importHref. The new
>   method can be invoked from an element as this.importHref. Outside an
>   element, it can be called as as Polymer.Base.importHref.

So...

```
this.importHref(["yourComponent.html"], function() {})
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the method I use for dynamically importing elements.  I use [vulcanizer](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) to split up my elements into logical modules.  Then I use Polymer.import:

**Polymer 0.5**

```
Polymer.import( ['/elements/'+this.module+'-module.html'], function() {
    console.log('/elements/'+this.module+'-module.html loaded');
    this.onComplete();
}.bind(this));
```

**Update Polymer 1.0**

Just use the link[rel="import"] tag

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
link.setAttribute('href', 'elements/app-module.html');
document.body.appendChild(link)
```

Comment: ok, thanks. One question, where is this method located? I mean where do you put it? inside the "ready" event? outside the polymer constructor...

Comment: Sorry, didn't add that.  I use this inside another custom element in a normal method call.  Basically my app loads with polymer and some custom elements, checks a flag, then loads the module (more elements) based on the flag.  My guess would be you can use the Polymer.import() anytime after the 'polymer-ready' window event fires.

Comment: This works fine on stable at the moment but on Canary it breaks. If you create the element immediately in the import callback it does not get prepared. It takes about 1-100 ms for the ready() callback to fire.

Comment: This doesn't work in version 1.0 :( Does anyone know what the latest method for importing is?

Comment: @7immy Just use the link tag, see above.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? I haven't tested some of this (the WebComponentsReady event may only fire on window), but if you can post a jsbin or codepin that would help:

```
Polymer('window-base', {
  name: 'Finder',
  domReady: function() {
    this.nameChanged();
  },
  nameChanged: function() {
    var importElem = document.createElement('link');
    importElem.rel = 'import';
    importElem.href = 'app-window/' + name + '-app.html';
    importElem.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var app = document.createElement(this.name + "-app");
      this.$.app.appendChild(app);
    }.bind(this));
    this.appendChild(importElem);
  }
});
```

Comment: I attempted to try this solution with no success - resulting me in forming my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435057/polymer-create-a-general-custom-element

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution also works for Polymer 2

Link to [Polymer 2 importHref docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/#function-Polymer.importHref)

```
Polymer.importHref([`bower_components/${plugin}/${plugin}.html`], () => {
    //on load
}
```