# Polymer: Create a "general" custom element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I am attempting to build an element with attributes that would specify which element should take place of this element.

I have a 3d-card flip element that I am using fo this purposes in the index.html that is defined as:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
        </script>
        <link rel="import" href="elements/general-element.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <general-element 
            name="card-flip" 
            address="elements/card-flip.html">
            <front>
                FRONT
            </front>
            <back>
                BACK
            </back>
        </general-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

The general-element.html is defined here:

```
<link rel="import" 
    href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="general-element" attributes="name address">
    <template>
        <div id="element_here">
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>

      function addElementToDOM( element_name, _that ) {
          var elem = _that.shadowRoot.querySelector( "#element_here" );
          add_elem = document.createElement( element_name );
          elem.appendChild( add_elem );
      }

        Polymer ( 'general-element', {
          ready: function() {
              if ( 
                  ( this.address != undefined ) && 
                  ( this.name != undefined ) ) {

                  Polymer.import( 
                      [this.address], 
                      addElementToDOM( this.name, this )
                  );
              }
          }
        } );
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

WARNING: The output is a blank with an error in the console saying  *Attributes on card-flip were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.*

Can this be achieved in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s hard to say what you are trying to achieve, but I would point at some glitches within your code and provide the working version with `paper-button` instead of `flip-card` (since I have no code of `flip-card`.)

**TL;DR** Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/yO865EkclZAsWBhzVSU4?p=preview

1. The main issue with your code is that you call function `addElementToDOM` instead of passing it as a callback as requested by [`Polymer.import`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/helpers.html#using-dynamic-html-imports). `function() { addElementToDOM(...); }` would be OK.
2. You use hyphen-less names for custom elements (like `front` and `back`) which is conventionally prohibited. Please use dashed as in my example.
3. You have your function polluted into global space for no reason. I put it inside an element.
4. You were likely want to puts your custom `flip-card` between `front` and `back`, but there is no vestige of `content select='front/back'` tag
   inside your template.
5. You are trying to access `shadowRoot` in improper way. You might want to take a look at `getDistributedNodes` function, but in this case it’s easier to use naming convention and address an element simply by `this.$.elementHere`.
6. You are supposed to explicitly specify `<body unresolved>` for the polyfill to take care about unresolved things.

The working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Add paper button</title>
  <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"> 
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <polymer-element name="general-element" attributes="name address">
    <template>
      <content select='my-front'></content>
      <div id="elementHere">
      </div>
      <content select='my-back'></content>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer ({
        addElementToDOM: function ( element_name ) {
          var elem = this.$.elementHere;
          add_elem = document.createElement( element_name );
          add_elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('¡Hola!'));
          elem.appendChild( add_elem );
        },

        domReady: function() {
          if ( this.address && this.name ) {
            var self = this;
            Polymer.import( 
              [self.address], 
              function() { self.addElementToDOM( self.name ); }
            );
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
  <general-element 
      name="paper-button" 
      address="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
      <my-front>
          FRONT
      </my-front>
      <my-back>
          BACK
      </my-back>
  </general-element>
</body>
</html>
```

I bet, your code could be working by applying the fix #1 but I strongly suggest you to fix other glitches as well. Hope it helps.

*P.S.* Why on the earth you needed to dynamically import your element? What’s wrong with simple

```
    <template>
      <content select='my-front'></content>
 <!-- ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ -->
      <flip-card></flip-card>
      <content select='my-back'></content>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, helped a lot and I also learned new stuff from your observations. The reason why I needed a general element like this is because the front end of the project will dynamically change according to fed data and user actions.

Comment: OK, nice to hear the answer was helpful.